# Cómo hacer una convolución que reduce el tamaño para simular una cámara

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Estoy simulando una cámara que se mueve en el espacio y apunta a un plano negro con formas.

El plano es una matriz:

```
np.zeros((x,y,3),dtype=np.uint8)
```

La cámara esta definida con una posición (xc,yc,zc). `z` es la altura y las coordenadas están en el mismo marco de referencia que las del "area/plano"

Cuando la cámara sube en z aumenta su campo de vista en 1 pixel en x e y pero tiene que transformarlo en una imagen en una resolución fija.

Para ello lo que hago es una convolución 2D en cada uno de los canales de color con una matriz de unos y calculando la media de esos pixeles (luego podría usar otras matrices).

Mi problema es que se hacerlo con bucles pero no sé transformarlo en notación de numpy y va muy lento.

El código de los bucles es algo así:

```
M = np.ones((zc+1,zc+1))
for i in range(resx+zc):
 for j in range(resy+zc):
  for chanel in range(3):
    pov[i,j,chanel]=np.sum(M*viewArea(area,pos))1/((zc+1)*(zc+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Es muy sencillo lo puedes hacer con **OpenCV**, simplemente le aplicas las convolución a la imagen:

```
import cv2

M = cv2.imread('...') # Cargamos la imagen 
K = (1.0/25.0)*np.ones((5,5)) # Ponemos el kernel de convolución que queramos
C = cv2.filter2D(M, -1, K) # Hacemos la convolución
```

Así tendríamos la convolución hecha